# asio 1.11.0 standalone wrap not correct... or is it me?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Given the following test program:

```
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    asio::io_service ios1, ios2;
    asio::io_service::strand s2(ios2);

    auto test_func = wrap(s2, [&] {
        assert(s2.running_in_this_thread());
    });

    auto wrap_test_func = wrap(ios1, test_func);

    wrap_test_func();

    ios1.run_one();
    ios2.run_one();

}
```

My understanding is that this program should not assert.

`wrap_test_func` is wrapped into `io_service` `ios1`. The function it is wrapping is wrapped into `strand` `s2` (which uses `ios2`).

As I understand it, calling `wrap_test_func` should be equivalent to `dispatch(ios1, test_func)` which should then dispatch the lambda in `s2`).

However, it looks as if wrap has unwrapped the inner wrapper.

Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: I am not sure how you compiled this, as I do not find any global wrap functions. Using the member level wrap, I could not see the assert happening though

Comment: @Arunmu this is not boost::asio. it's the standalone version 1.11.0

Comment: Yeah, even I am using the standalone version 1.11.0 (header only). `g++ -std=c++11 -DASIO_STANDALONE  -o wrap_test wrap_test.cc -I /Users/arunmu/asio-master/asio/include/` is how I am building it.

Comment: @Arunmu may I ask where you downloaded your version?

Comment: It's been quite a while since I had this downloaded. I think it was from http://think-async.com/

Answer (score 5):

Turns out that it was my misunderstanding.

Here's a copy of the reply by Asio's author:

> Hi Richard,
>
> Yes this behaviour is deliberate. However, in the networking TS and
>   the latest code on the master branch this facility has been renamed
>   from wrap (which implied adding another layer as you expected) to
>   bind_executor. This function simply imbues the object with an
>   associated executor; if it already had one it is overridden.
>
> If you need true wrapping then you should explicitly wrap your inner
>   handler in an outer function object (or lambda), and have the outer
>   handler dispatch() the inner handler on its "associated executor". As
>   you're writing your own asynchronous operation, I suggest adopting the
>   following pattern (documented in the networking TS as part of the
>   "requirements on asynchronous operations"):
>
> - Ask the handler for its associated executor using get_associated_executor.
> - post() the handler to that executor if your operation finishes immediately.
> - dispatch() the handler to that executor otherwise.
>
> So (untested code, may require tip of master branch):
>
> ```
>     template<class Task, class Handler>
>     void async_execute(implementation& impl, Task&& task, Handler&& handler)
>     {
>         ...
>
>         auto ex = asio::get_associated_executor(handler get_io_context());
>
>         // this is immediate completion, so we use post()
>
>         if (not impl)
>         {
>             post(ex, [handler = std::forward<Handler>(handler)]() mutable
>                  {
>                      promise_type promise;
>                      promise.set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(system_error(errors::null_handle)));
>                      handler(promise.get_future());
>                  });
>             return;
>         }
>
>         // this is not immediate completion, so we use dispatch()
>         // (NOTE: assumes this->post_execute() does not run the task)
>
>         // Optional. Really only needed if your io_context participates in the
>         // async operation in some way not shown in this snippet, and not
>         // simply as a channel for delivering the handler.
>         auto io_work = make_work_guard(get_io_contet());
>
>         auto handler_work = make_work_guard(ex);
>         auto impl_ptr = impl.get();
>         auto async_handler = [this,
>                               ex,
>                               impl_ptr,
>                               io_work, handler_work,
>                               handler = std::forward<Handler>(handler)]
>         (detail::long_running_task_op::identifier ident,
>          auto future) mutable
>         {
>             assert(impl_ptr);
>             io_work.reset();
>             dispatch(ex, [handler = std::move(handler), future = std::move(future)]() mutable
>                  {
>                      handler(std::move(future));
>                  });
>             assert(impl_ptr);
>             impl_ptr->remove_op(ident);
>         };
>
>         ...
>
>         this->post_execute();
>     }
> ```
>
> Hope this helps.
>
> Cheers, Chris

Comment: Did it just get more complicated ?

Comment: @Arunmu not from the client users perspective. Service implementors (like me) have some new skills to learn, but the changes are good - particularly being able to carry move-only objects into completion handlers (such as futures), which is what I am doing here.